# ¿Cómo imprimir la serie 2/1 + 4/3 + 6/5... en C?

Tags: c, bucle-for, condiciones, while, else

Mi ejercicio pide que el usuario digite un numero entero y de acuerdo a ese numero será el numero de operaciones que tenga la serie. Por ejemplo: El usuario digita el numero 5. La serie tiene que ser así: 2/1 + 4/3 + 6/5 + 8/7 + 10/9. Y mostrar el resultado de dicha operación con un numero con decimales. Tengo éste código:

```
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    float res, i, j, suma;

    printf("\nIngresa un numero entero positivo: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for (i=2; i < n+n; i += 2)
    {
        for (j = 1; j < n+n-1; j += 2)
        {
        }
    }

    res = i/j;
    suma = res + res;

    printf("\n%.2f / %.2f = %.2f",i,j,suma);
    
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Sinceramente no sé si lo estoy haciendo bien o no, soy nuevo en la programación y si me cuesta un poco entender ejercicios como estos. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

En este caso puedes definir dos variables para almacenar el numerador (siempre comienza en 2) y el denominador (siempre comienza en 1) y con ayuda del ciclo `for` puedes ir aumentando el numerador y el denominador en dos (2) cada ciclo.

Recuerda que el resultado va a ser igual al resultado de la iteración anterior y la divisón de la iteración actual. Se podría representar así resultadoActual = resultadoAnterior + numeradorActual/denominadorActual

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int i, entrada, numerador = 2, denominador = 1;
    double suma = 0.0;

    printf("Número de operaciones de la serie:\n");
    scanf("%d", &entrada);

    for (i = 1; i <= entrada; i++)
    {
        suma = suma + (double)numerador/denominador;
        numerador = numerador + 2;
        denominador = denominador + 2;
    }
    
    printf("Resultado = %f\n", suma);
    
}
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Podrias compactar aún más el código usando `(denominador+1)/denominador` y eliminando `numerador`

Answer (score 0):

Con esto podrás mostrar todos los elementos de la serie y el resultado:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
int main()
{
int n;
printf("\nIngresa un número entero positivo: ");
scanf("%d",&n);
std::string serie ="";
double suma =0.0;
int cantidad = 2*n;
for (int i=2; i <= cantidad; i += 2){
    serie+=std::to_string(i)+"/"+std::to_string(i-1);
    if(i<cantidad-1){
        serie+=" + ";
    }
    suma+=(double(i)/double(i-1));
}
std::cout << serie << " = " << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << suma;
}
```

Para `4`, imprime:
`2/1 + 4/3 + 6/5 + 8/7 = 5.68`

Para `5`, imprime:
`2/1 + 4/3 + 6/5 + 8/7 + 10/9 = 6.79`

Para `20`, imprime:
`2/1 + 4/3 + 6/5 + 8/7 + 10/9 + 12/11 + 14/13 + 16/15 + 18/17 + 20/19 + 22/21 + 24/23 + 26/25 + 28/27 + 30/29 + 32/31 + 34/33 + 36/35 + 38/37 + 40/39 = 22.48`

Si sólo te interesa el resultado:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
int n;
printf("\nIngresa un número entero positivo: ");
scanf("%d",&n);
double suma =0.0;
int cantidad = 2*n;
for (int i=2; i <= cantidad; i += 2){
    suma+=(double(i)/double(i-1));
}
printf("\n%.2f",suma);
}
```